# Connecting with the database using C#

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm trying to get data from a Database and all time I get the next error:

> No se controló System.NullReferenceException   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un
>   objeto.   Source=ImeApps   StackTrace:
>          en ComunCD.getConexionIRATI() en C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\ImeApps\ComunCD.cs:línea 64
>          en EmpresasCD.getEmpresas() en C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\ImeApps\EmpresasCD.cs:línea 41
>          en ImeApps.Principal.abrirSeleccionEmpresaEspera() en C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\ImeApps\Principal.cs:línea 92
>          en ImeApps.Principal.abrirSeleccionEmpresa() en C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\ImeApps\Principal.cs:línea 82
>          en ImeApps.Principal.menuItem4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en
>   C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\ImeApps\Principal.cs:línea 77
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e,
>   ToolStripItemEventType met)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          en System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          en ImeApps.Program.Main() en C:\Desarrollo\VisualStudio2010\ImeApps\ImeApps\Program.cs:línea 16
>          en System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          en System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          en System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
>          en System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
>          en System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
>          en System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext)
>          en System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
>          en Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
>          en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

What I am doing is the following:

```
public class ComunCD
    {
    private static SqlConnection _sqlConnectionIRATI;

    public static void conectarBDIRATI()
        {
            _sqlConnectionIRATI = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CONEXION_IRATI"].ToString());
            _sqlConnectionIRATI.Open();
        }

    public static SqlConnection getConexionIRATI()
    {
        if (_sqlConnectionIRATI == null)
        {
            //conectarBDIRATI();
        }
        if (_sqlConnectionIRATI.State != ConnectionState.Open) // HERE I GET THE ERROR
        {
            _sqlConnectionIRATI.Open();
        }
        return _sqlConnectionIRATI;
    }
```

What could am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `else if (_sqlConnectionIRATI.State != ConnectionState.Open)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `_sqlConnectionIRATI` is `null` you should not test for `State`: add `else`:

```
    if (_sqlConnectionIRATI == null)
    {
        //conectarBDIRATI();
    }
    else if (_sqlConnectionIRATI.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
    {
        _sqlConnectionIRATI.Open();
    }
```

Or you should *create* an instance:

```
    // If _sqlConnectionIRATI is null, we create it 
    if (_sqlConnectionIRATI == null)
      conectarBDIRATI();

    // _sqlConnectionIRATI is guaranteed to be not null: 
    if (_sqlConnectionIRATI.State != ConnectionState.Open)  
      _sqlConnectionIRATI.Open();
```